# How to call cloudinary module from my controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, cloudinary, mean-stack

I am biulding a MEAN-STACK application (this is new for me) and started from this template: https://github.com/linnovate/mean

I want to add a module (called cloudinary) so I followed this: 
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_upload#direct_uploading_environment_setup

(npm install, bower etc.... is done)

I am stuck at this line (don't know how to do it):

> cloudinary.uploader.image_upload_tag('image_id', { callback:
>   cloudinary_cors });

In my app there is a controller and a service. If I put this in the controller I get the message 'cloudinary is undifined'. Maybe I should put it in the service file but I don't know how to. I create a form in my html page with an input that is supposed to upload a file calling the 'cloudyPost()' function from my controller.

Here is the code of my controller, service and page:

mycars.js (service):

```
//Cars service used for car REST endpoint
angular.module('mean.mycars').factory('Cars', ['$resource', function($resource) {
 return $resource('cars/:carId', {
     carId: '@_id'
 }, {
     update: {
         method: 'PUT'
     }
 });
}]);
```

mycars.js (controller):

```
angular.module('mean.mycars').controller('MyCarsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Cars',
function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cars) {

 $scope.cloudPost = function() {
        cloudinary.uploader.image_upload_tag('image_id', { callback: cloudinary_cors });
    };

[.... some other  code ....]
 }
```

My html page:

```
<section data-ng-controller="MyCarsController" data-ng-init="findOneOrCreate()">
   <form role="form" data-ng-submit="cloudyPost()">
      <p>Public ID: <input type="text" name="title"/></p>
      <p>Image: <input type="file" name="image"/></p>
      <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send to Cloudy!</button>  </p>      
    </form>
</section>
```

Can you please help me integrate all this together and make it work. Thank you.

Add here is the js included in my pages at the end):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/ng-grid/build/ng-grid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.cloudinary.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/articles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/car.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/header.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/mycars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/directives.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/filters.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/services/articles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/services/cars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/services/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/services/mycars.js"></script>

<!-- Livereload script rendered -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you included the script `jquery.cloudinary.js` and the dependent script `jquery.fileupload.js`? AND after including these scripts, you have then added your AngularJS scripts?

Comment: Yes I have tose script (I edited my question with page sources). I don't understant the seconde part of your question about Angular scripts. How can I check that ?

Comment: You first add the cloudinary scripts. Then you proceed to add the angularjs library and then the controllers and so on. By add, I mean the `script` tag - `<script src="">`

Comment: Still not working. I have post on cloudinary forum, they say that the  cloudinary.uploader.image_upload_tag should be on the server side (wich make sense). But then how should I do to have it call from my button (html) to my server throught my controller (and service maybe?) ?

Comment: The way I have used Cloudinary in my application is to first make use of [AngularJS file uploader plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html) on the client side and then user [Cloudinary's Nodejs module](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration) to upload the file to cloudinary - did you try that?

Comment: The `image_upload_tag ` element is related to Direct uploads from the browser. It doesn't go through your server at all. A hidden field is generated on the client-side after the upload terminates to support notifying your server with the new image data.
The magic happens in the included jQuery files.
See: http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_image_uploads_from_the_browser_to_the_cloud_with_jquery

For more guidance feel free to [contact Cloudinary directly](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)